# Altering background color of button to flow into header on select

Tags: html, css, button, selected

I'm trying to altar two buttons (Easy, Hard) on a web app I'm building. I am trying to alter them to remove their borders, and when a button is selected, I want to background to flow up into the header as a visual indication for being selected.

**Note: I am linking Bootstrap 4 at the moment.**

Current Visual:

[image: 1]

Desired Visual:

[image: 2]

```css
body {
    background-color: #232323;
}

.header {
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    padding: 1.5rem;
    background-color: #66b0c4;
}

.header h1 {
    margin: 0;
}

.square {
    width: 30%;
    background: purple;
    padding-bottom: 30%;
    float: left;
    margin: 1.66%;
}

#container {
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#stripe {
    background-color: white ;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
}

.selected {
    background:#66b0c4;
    border: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
    <h1>The Great <br><span id="colorDisplay">RGB</span><be> 
    Color Game</h1>
</div>
<div id="stripe">
    <button id="reset">New Colors</button>
    <span id="message"></span>
    <button id="easyBtn">Easy</button>
    <button id="hardBtn" class="selected">Hard</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can help you.

```css
body {
    background-color: #232323;
}

.header {
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    padding: 1.5rem;
    background-color: #66b0c4;
}

.header h1 {
    margin: 0;
}

.square {
    width: 30%;
    background: purple;
    padding-bottom: 30%;
    float: left;
    margin: 1.66%;
}

#container {
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#stripe {
    background-color: white ;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

.selected {
    background:#66b0c4;
  border: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  position: relative;
}

.selected::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: -10px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #66b0c4;
  height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
    <h1>The Great <br><span id="colorDisplay">RGB</span><be> 
    Color Game</h1>
</div>
<div id="stripe">
    <button id="reset">New Colors</button>
    <span id="message"></span>
    <button id="easyBtn">Easy</button>
    <button id="hardBtn" class="selected">Hard</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adjusting the height of background on the selected class. Also solved the selection issue with

```
*:focus {
    outline: 0 !important;
}
```

**CSS Now:**

```
.selected {
    background:#66b0c4;
    border: none;
    height: 30px;
    
}

*:focus {
    outline: 0 !important;
}
```